# Parsing date from fetched dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas

would you please take a look at it? I am trying to have one column with index 1980-12-12 so basically date in my dataframe. Currently when I try to choose this column I cannot target it.

I know how to do it for csv/excel file but how can I index/create column with Date such as 1980-12-12?

Thank you!

Function to get data for my volume graph:

```
from yahooquery import Ticker

def getVolumeGraph():
    aapl = Ticker('aapl')

    df = aapl.history(period='max', interval='1d')

    print(df.info())
    print(df)

    #return fig
```

df

```
                           high       close  ...  dividends  splits
1980-12-12 14:30:00    0.515625    0.513393  ...        0.0     0.0
1980-12-15 14:30:00    0.488839    0.486607  ...        0.0     0.0
1980-12-16 14:30:00    0.453125    0.450893  ...        0.0     0.0
1980-12-17 14:30:00    0.464286    0.462054  ...        0.0     0.0
1980-12-18 14:30:00    0.477679    0.475446  ...        0.0     0.0
...                         ...         ...  ...        ...     ...
2020-06-03 13:30:00  326.200012  325.119995  ...        0.0     0.0
2020-06-04 13:30:00  325.619995  322.320007  ...        0.0     0.0
2020-06-05 13:30:00  331.750000  331.500000  ...        0.0     0.0
2020-06-08 13:30:00  333.600006  333.459991  ...        0.0     0.0
2020-06-09 13:30:00  345.609985  343.989990  ...        0.0     0.0
```

df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 9957 entries, 1980-12-12 14:30:00 to 2020-06-09 13:30:00
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   high       9957 non-null   float64
 1   close      9957 non-null   float64
 2   low        9957 non-null   float64
 3   volume     9957 non-null   float64
 4   open       9957 non-null   float64
 5   adjclose   9957 non-null   float64
 6   dividends  9957 non-null   float64
 7   splits     9957 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(8)
memory usage: 1020.1 KB
```

Comment: `df.index.date`?

Comment: What do you mean "you cannot target it"? What's the desired output?

Comment: It's not a column, it's the df's index. `df.info()` makes this very obvious to you: "DatetimeIndex: 9957 entries, 1980-12-12 14:30:00 to 2020-06-09 13:30:00"

Comment: Oh yea, morning mind blow. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some potential solutions you could use:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
from datetime import datetime, date

aapl = Ticker('aapl')
df = aapl.history(period='max', interval='1d')
```

df

```
                      volume       low      high     close      open      adjclose  dividends  splits
1980-12-12 14:30:00  117258400.0  0.513393  0.515625  0.513393  0.513393  0.405683        0.0     0.0
1980-12-15 14:30:00   43971200.0  0.486607  0.488839  0.486607  0.488839  0.384517        0.0     0.0
1980-12-16 14:30:00   26432000.0  0.450893  0.453125  0.450893  0.453125  0.356296        0.0     0.0
1980-12-17 14:30:00   21610400.0  0.462054  0.464286  0.462054  0.462054  0.365115        0.0     0.0
1980-12-18 14:30:00   18362400.0  0.475446  0.477679  0.475446  0.475446  0.375698        0.0     0.0
```

Option 1. Get rid of the the timestamp and rename the index:

```
df.index = df.index.normalize()
df.index.name = 'Date'

Date        volume       low      high     close      open       adjclose  dividends  splits                                                                                
1980-12-12  117258400.0  0.513393  0.515625  0.513393  0.513393  0.405683        0.0     0.0
1980-12-15   43971200.0  0.486607  0.488839  0.486607  0.488839  0.384517        0.0     0.0
1980-12-16   26432000.0  0.450893  0.453125  0.450893  0.453125  0.356296        0.0     0.0
1980-12-17   21610400.0  0.462054  0.464286  0.462054  0.462054  0.365115        0.0     0.0
1980-12-18   18362400.0  0.475446  0.477679  0.475446  0.475446  0.375698        0.0     0.0
```

Option 2: Just add a date column in front

```
df.insert(0, 'Date', df.index.normalize())

                          Date      open     close      high       volume  \
1980-12-12 14:30:00 1980-12-12  0.513393  0.513393  0.515625  117258400.0   
1980-12-15 14:30:00 1980-12-15  0.488839  0.486607  0.488839   43971200.0   
1980-12-16 14:30:00 1980-12-16  0.453125  0.450893  0.453125   26432000.0   
1980-12-17 14:30:00 1980-12-17  0.462054  0.462054  0.464286   21610400.0   
1980-12-18 14:30:00 1980-12-18  0.475446  0.475446  0.477679   18362400.0
```

Option 3: Add a Date column in front and then reset the index

```
df.insert(0, 'Date', df.index.normalize())
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

        Date      high       volume     close      open       low  adjclose  \
0 1980-12-12  0.515625  117258400.0  0.513393  0.513393  0.513393  0.405683   
1 1980-12-15  0.488839   43971200.0  0.486607  0.488839  0.486607  0.384517   
2 1980-12-16  0.453125   26432000.0  0.450893  0.453125  0.450893  0.356296   
3 1980-12-17  0.464286   21610400.0  0.462054  0.462054  0.462054  0.365115   
4 1980-12-18  0.477679   18362400.0  0.475446  0.475446  0.475446  0.375698
```

It's hard to be sure what you're after, but maybe a quick tutorial in pandas wouldn't hurt
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/index.htm since you seem to be thinking that Excel knowledge is directly translated into python pandas without a learning curve.